# if else statement with 2 sounds

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

trying to build this code here, but it's ain't going so well ....
have 2 sound files that each will play when a Bool status is met ....but only one sound plays and the other don't !! where is my mistake in the else statement ?

```
 func answersSound (answerPickedSound: Bool) {
    if answerPickedSound  {
        if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Rbeep-02", withExtension: "mp3") {
            do { player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
                player.play()
            } catch {
                print("Right")
            }
        } else  {
           if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Wbeep-03", withExtension: "mp3") {
                do { player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
                    player.play()
                } catch {
                    print("Wrong!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to set the `else` part to the outside `if` statement i.e `if answerPickedSound`, currently `else`  part is never run because `if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Rbeep-02", withExtension: "mp3") {` is always non-nil.

Comment: can't really grasp what you are saying ...? can you elaborate please ?

Comment: check woof's answer

Comment: Doesn't Swift have a debugger? Seems to me two minutes with it would have been faster than coming here and posting a question and formatting the code.

Comment: @KenWhite yes ken you are right ... but it might be easy for you to debug as a professional programmer ... i never debugged and honestly have no clue how to do so, hence my question here, so i can learn from you gents .... but i will be more than happy if you can recommend some debugging tutorials ... Thanks

Comment: A debugger is one of the most important tools in a programmer's toolbox. It's never too early to learn how to use one. You don't really need a tutorial - learn how to set a breakpoint, run to a breakpoint, and step through the code. Steps are usually *execute next line*, *step into* a function call, *step over* (which means *go execute the function without tracing in, but stop on the line after when it returns*). It allows you to follow the execution path of the code, examine variables, etc.. In this case, it would have shown you exactly why the if..else didn't work as you expected.

Comment: @KenWhite ... thanks for the tip ... however, the code is running now and i'm trying to use print and BP to debug but ... i don't know how BP would have shown me where the issue would be ... its just going through the code line by line as i click the pass/move over button ...

Comment: Yes, and that would have shown you that you put the second sound in the wrong place, because it would not have stepped into the code the way you expected it to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you've put the second sound in wrong place

Try this

```
func answersSound (answerPickedSound: Bool) {
    if answerPickedSound  {
        if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Rbeep-02", withExtension: "mp3") {
            do { player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
                player.play()
            } catch {
                print("Right")
            }
        }
    }else{
        if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Wbeep-03", withExtension: "mp3") {
                do { player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
                    player.play()
                } catch {
                    print("Wrong!")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

=====EDIT=====

My recommendations to make code more readable and easy to debug

```
//leave this method as is, but move additional code in separated method
func answersSound (answerPickedSound: Bool) {
    //now check boolean and play proper sound
    if answerPickedSound  {
        playSound(name: "Rbeep-02")
    }else{
        playSound(name: "Wbeep-03")
    }

    //Or
    //Use ternary operator
    let soundName = answerPickedSound ? "Rbeep-02" : "Wbeep-03"
    playSound(name: soundName)
}

func playSound(name: String) {
   //use guard else statement to check the sound in bundle
   guard let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "mp3") else {
       print("No sound in bundle for name: \(name)")
       return
   }

   do { 
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
        player.play()
   } catch {
        print("Error playing sound for name: \(name)")
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... it worked .... but have no clue why xc did not give me a waring of the extra bracket ?

Comment: @AmirFendi check my answer one more time, I've typed some recommendations for you. Try to make your code simpler for reading and debugging

Comment: can't understand this:
[//leave this method as is, but move additional code in separated method]
what additional code ? where is it ?

Comment: @AmirFendi it means that I didn't change the definition of that method, but moved the main functionality of playing sounds into the separated method playSound(name: String)

Comment: So the additional code should be used with the first method ? and if yes ... how ?

Comment: so this code works by it's own without the need for the extra lines ? 
func answersSound (answerPickedSound: Bool) {
    //now check boolean and play proper sound
    if answerPickedSound  {
        playSound(name: "Rbeep-02")
    }else{
        playSound(name: "Wbeep-03")
    }

Comment: @AmirFendi what do you mean? The code below ====Edit==== is complete. It's just an example how to make your code better for debugging. And inside  the answerSound method you can use if else statement or the ternary operator, it's up to you.

Comment: the top part gives me an error: Use of unresolved identifier 'playSound'

Comment: Have you added the method playSound to your code after your first method answersSound?

Comment: where this part goes ? 

{let soundName = answerPickedSound ? "Rbeep-02" : "Wbeep-03"
    playSound(name: soundName)}

Comment: i really don't understand .... are there 2 separate functions or linked to each other ? what goes where ?

Comment: @AmirFendi sorry, can't understand what you're asking. You need to add only one method playSound to your code and change your method answersSound to use "if else" statement or a ternary operator to play proper sound using added method playSound

Comment: here what i did with your code .... i pasted all your code and commented out mine ... it's working ... because honestly, i have no clue what you are saying: (You need to add only one method playSound to your code and change your method answersSound to use "if else" statement or a ternary operator to play proper sound using added method playSound)
so basically i pasted all your code ....